# All checkboxes are selected (or not) by default when loading model in Angular2

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular2-ngmodel

I have a weird issue.

In my html pages, I have the following code:

```
<form>
<tr *ngFor="let role of userRoles" style="width:100%;" >
    <td style="width:37px;">
        <input class="uicheckbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="role.IsActive" name="isActive{{role.roleId}}" (click)="onCheck(role)" />
    </td>
    <td>{{role.Name}}</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

I'm bringing in a model that has an Array of roles, some of which have set IsActive to true, some to false. The checkbox should be checked based on the role.IsActive property.  But for some reason, all checkboxes are (un)checked when the model loads. Why is this happening?

EDIT:  Looking at this even further, the state of all the checkboxes are dependent on the last element of the Array.  So if the last role is checked, all checkboxes are checked.

EDIT 2:  Added the form tag as it causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `[value]="role.isActive"` inside of your checkbox in order to set the individual value. This is also described in the official Angular2 guide. Also properties should start with lower case. You have `role.IsActive` which is against the Angular2 style guide

Comment: That didn't work.  Every other checkbox is still checked/unchecked.

Comment: [NgValue}="role.isActive"

Comment: You should provide a plunker, in my project it is working perfectly